# TS2345: Argument of type 'Params' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CommonResult'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, fetch

I'm trying to make a put fetch using axios on my React project, but it throws an error that parameter variable is not assignable to return variable.
For the code below, can't 'CommonResult' and 'Params' be totally different type?
CommonResult is response type and params should be data to send for request.
Why is it looking for 'Params' within Result type??

```
import axios from "axios";

const BaseURLV1 = '/api/v1';
export const fetchV1 = axios.create({
    baseURL: BaseURLV1,
});

type Params = {
    password: string,
    newPassword: string,
};

export const MemberPasswordModifyPutFetch = (params: Params) =>
    fetchV1.put<CommonResult>('/member/password', params);
```

[image]

Comment: Anybody knows? :(

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error: https://tsplay.dev/N9JXJm